# CMake linker flag end-group duplicate is removed

Tags: cmake

I want to use multiple shared libraries in an executable, but the linker flag `-Wl,--end-group` for a child static library somehow is missing. The following is my `CMakeLists.txt` (executable `a` depends on `b` and `d`. `b` itself depends on `c`):

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.12)
PROJECT(ORDER_TEST CXX C)

#######
#  a  #
#######
ADD_EXECUTABLE(a a/a.cpp a/inc/a.h)

TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(a PUBLIC a/inc)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(a PRIVATE
    "-Wl,--no-whole-archive"
    "-Wl,--start-group"
    d
    b
    "-Wl,--end-group"
)

#######
#  b  #
#######
ADD_LIBRARY(b STATIC b/b.cpp b/inc/b.h)

TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(b PUBLIC b/inc)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(b PUBLIC
    "-Wl,--no-whole-archive"
    "-Wl,--start-group"
    c
    "-Wl,--end-group"
)

#######
#  c  #
#######
ADD_LIBRARY(c STATIC c/c.cpp c/inc/c.h)

TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(c PUBLIC c/inc)

#######
#  d  #
#######
ADD_LIBRARY(d STATIC d/d.cpp d/inc/d.h)

TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(d PUBLIC d/inc)
```

Now, the final linker command (taken from the link.txt, reformatted) is:

```
/usr/bin/c++ \
    CMakeFiles/a.dir/a/a.cpp.o \
    -o a \
    -rdynamic \
    -Wl,--no-whole-archive \
    -Wl,--start-group \
    libd.a \
    libb.a \
    -Wl,--end-group \
    -Wl,--no-whole-archive \
    -Wl,--start-group \
    libc.a
```

The final `-Wl,--end-group` is missing.
To check whether CMake maybe just lost the last argument, I added some arbitrary argument (`-Wl,-s`) to the end of `b`'s `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES`, which appeared at the very end in the generated linker command (where I expected it to appear), but `-Wl,--end-group` is still nowhere in sight. (If I also use the flag `-fuse-ld=gold`, then the compilation aborts with an error complaining that the closing `--end-group` is missing.)

## Question

Why is the final `-Wl,--end-group` missing? How can I make it reappear at the correct place (at the end, after `libc.a`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe adding linker arguments like that is not the CMake idiomatic way.

You could utilize the target property [LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY.html) by setting to 3+ (it is 2 by default for all targets) with `set_target_properties` command. This instructs CMake to construct the link line so that the linker will scan through the [strongly connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) of the dependence graph at least as many times as specified by the property.

*However*, I'm not sure why you need `--start/end-group` options since you don't seem to have dependency cycles in the above `CMakeLists.txt`. Simply laying out the dependencies for each library using `target_link_libraries` should work.

Comment: Your last paragraph is what I needed - I needed the grouping and no-whole-archive flags for *some* libraries in the top level library, and after refactoring also used it in the other static libraries (did not reevaluate, whether it is still necessary), but with a fresh look at it, you are right, I can simply list the libraries without other flags and be done with it. Thank you.

Comment: I hate all of these cmake hacks. We need to construct a link line. It's really really simple. Some linker commands go at the front, and some at the back. Instead of cmake providing some straightforward way of doing this, we have all of these bespoke "solutions" for different problems.

How do you use --start-group and --end-group with cmake? Sometimes that's just what you need to do.

Comment: @Zendel I sympathize and mostly agree, but I'm not sure what's the utility of this comment. If there's an actual question, maybe a separate post is more appropriate. Typically, conversational style comments are discouraged (lounge areas are better for this), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).